# Can I quickly delete all local music?

Tags: ios, itunes-match

I subscribe to [iTunes Match](http://www.apple.com/itunes/itunes-match/). I recently did a massive song metadata (tag/ID3) update without using iTunes itself. This appears to have updated the metadata in iCloud, but another issue appeared.

In my Music list, for albums that changed more significantly, they are now listed twice. Once without a Cloud icon (the previously downloaded version), and one with a Cloud icon. There are many of these albums, and identifying them and manually deleting them has become cumbersome.

Is there a function within iOS to allow me to delete all locally downloaded music? Essentially resetting the Music library state?

Comment: If you're having troubles with duplicates, you can use File > Display Duplicates... then COMMAND+A, Delete... to delete all duplicates

Comment: There is no Command+A on an iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Settings; Tap on `General` > `Usage` > `Music`, then swipe across `All Music` and tap the delete button that appeared.

That should delete all your local music.

Comment: Aha! I kept trying to swipe the Music category, not going into the category and swiping across the actual music type (vice Audiobooks/iTunes U/Podcasts).

Answer (score 0):

Be aware! If you delete the one without the iCloud symbol, there might be a chance you'll get an "File not found"-error when trying to play the song in the iCloud!

Comment: Surely things I deleted from iCloud via my iPhone will no longer be listed whatsoever?